# How to use MATLAB Code for Monte Carlo Simulation?

Tags: matlab, statistics, montecarlo

```
`n = 10000; 
Min= Minimum Value;
Max= Maximum Value;
Mode= Most Likely Value;
X = [Min=5,Mode=7,Max=10];
Y = [Min=3,Mode=5,Max= 10];
Z = [Min=5,Mode=7,Max=12];
P= X*Y*Z;`
```

I have three parameters such as, X =( Min=5,Mode=7,Max=10); Y=(Min=3,Mode=5,Max=10); Z=(Min=5,Mode=7,Max=12). and P = X*Y*Z; Now how can I write a MATLAB Code for  Monte Carlo simulation for 10000 iteration to get P values? and how to plot normal distribution  and cumulative distribution of the out put P values?

Comment: What have you tried? SO doesn't answer questions where the user doesn't show that they've tried on their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should calculate mean and variance of each distribution, to model it with normal distribution, then:

```
Xrand = (Xvariance*randn(1,n)) + Xmean*ones(1,n);
Yrand = (Yvariance*randn(1,n)) + Ymean*ones(1,n);
Zrand = (Zvariance*randn(1,n)) + Zmean*ones(1,n);

P = Xrand.*Yrand.*Zrand;

plot(P);
```

If you don't want to model with normal distribution, then you'll need some toolbox or implement the distribution yourself.

Comment: Thanks you  hsgubert. Now, What will be the Markov chain Monte Carlo simulation code for the above problem?

Comment: Sorry, don't know much of Markov Chain other than what's written in Wikipedia. =)

Comment: If I want to use Min,Max and Mode value of the inputs then what change I have to made in the code?